# Retrieving entries from a partition in Hazelcast

Tags: partitioning, in-memory-database, hazelcast

Is it possible to retrieve the entries from a Partition when the Partition-id is given?

For example : If I enter the Partition-id as 3 , Can I get the entries in that particular partition only?

Please Help.!

Answer (score 1):

No, current API does not support this.

Comment: Ok thank you.! Is migration of partitions possible from one member to another manually? @javanes

Comment: Any plans of implementing them in future builds? @javanes